# How to pass the item from an each loop into a function

Tags: svelte

I have a component which contains:

```html
{#each menuItems as item}
<div  class="menu-item {item.selected ? 'selected' : ''}" on:click={select(item)}>
    ...stuff...
</div>
{/each}
```

menuItems is an array of objects:

```js
$: menuItem = [{
id: 'abc',
selected: true,
}]
```

I have a function called `select` which needs to take the item from the each loop as a parameter. How would I do this? The current example does not work due to `on:click` requiring a function like `on:click={submit}`. I have tried within quotation marks, and that did not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing `on:click={select(item)}` you are invoking the `select` function directly on render. You want to give `on:click` a function reference, and you could do that by creating a new inline function for every item in the loop.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/85abf88d04274accb037d4163f087651?version=3.5.4))**

```html
<script>
  const menuItems = [
    {
      id: 'abc',
      selected: true
    },
    {
      id: 'def',
      selected: false
    }
  ];

  function select(item) {
    alert(item.id);
  }
</script>

{#each menuItems as item}
  <div
    class="menu-item {item.selected ? 'selected' : ''}"
    on:click={() => select(item)}
  >
    {item.id}
  </div>
{/each}
```